# jQuery Select2 placeholder doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-select2

I am following this doc http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/ to create select box with `placeholder`. My problem is the `placeholder` doesn't work. Can you help to fix this code?

Code: Also at http://jsfiddle.net/VwGGU/3/

**HTML**:

```
<select style="width:300px" id="source">
    <optgroup label="Alaskan/Hawaiian Time Zone">
        <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
        <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Pacific Time Zone">
        <option value="CA">California</option>
        <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
        <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
        <option value="WA">Washington</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$("#e2").select2({
    placeholder: "Select a State",
    allowClear: true
});
```

The example above shows **"Alaska"** instead of **"Select a State"** as placeholder.

**UPDATE 1:**

Added `select2.js` now and empty `option`. It still doesn't show `placeholder`

**HTML**

```
<select style="width:300px" id="source" placeholder="testt test">
    <option></option>
    <optgroup label="Alaskan/Hawaiian Time Zone">
        <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
        <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Pacific Time Zone">
        <option value="CA">California</option>
        <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
        <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
        <option value="WA">Washington</option>
    </optgroup>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#source").select2({
        placeholder: "Select a State",
        allowClear: true
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VwGGU/6/

**UPDATE 2:**

Strange that jsfiddle gave error when I copied .css and .js link from github. This version works

**HTML**

```
<select style="width:300px" id="source" >
    <option></option>
    <optgroup label="Alaskan/Hawaiian Time Zone">
        <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
        <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Pacific Time Zone">
        <option value="CA">California</option>
        <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
        <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
        <option value="WA">Washington</option>
    </optgroup>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#source").select2({
        placeholder: "Select a State",
        allowClear: true
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VwGGU/9/

Comment: You're not including the JavaScript code for the plugin; just the CSS.

Comment: I made a mistake copying from local code

Comment: In my case it worked by adding `multiple=""` to the `select` tag. Then in the javascript I added the `maximumSelectionLength: 1,` option. Here is the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/latlov/VwGGU/167/) working quite good but in my project it does work.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Your `select` element have an id of `source` but you are targeting an `id` of `e2` in your jQuery selector, and you need an empty `<option>` tag

Comment: I just updated to insert empty `option` but it just shows that blank option instead of placeholder text.

Answer (score 45):

Have you done this:

> When placeholder is used for a non-multi-value select box, it requires that you include an empty  tag as your first option

Comment: Good suggestion, but until his test page is actually using the plugin code this change won't help :)

Comment: @Myles I've followed your suggestion, but I have not gotten this to work yet. Do you have a link to the source docs. I can't find this in the chosen manual.

Comment: @usumoio can you please post your code online? Happy to help but hard to debug with out seeing code :)

Comment: @Myles I messed up, I was working with a different tool and forgot what I was up too. I was at the office too late. Please disregard.

Answer (score 1):

```
$selectElement.select2({
    minimumResultsForSearch: -1,
    placeholder: 'Select Relatives'
}).on('select2-opening', function() {
    $(this).closest('li').find('input').attr('placeholder','Select Relative');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<select id="select2Box" class="form-control brand-select">
    <option value="">Select Franchise</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, one should also explain how and why this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You should add an empty option tag to the select.

```
<select data-placeholder="Chose number" data-allow-clear="true" data-width="50%">
    <option></option>
    <option value="1">Number one</option>
    <option value="2">Number two</option>
    <option value="3">Number three</option>
</select>
```

Check this link [Placeholder only works when there's an empty option element](https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/3553)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.In html you write the following code.

```
<select class="select2" multiple="multiple" placeholder="Select State">
    <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
    <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
</select>
```

And in your script write the below code.

```
<script>
         $( ".select2" ).select2( { } );
 </script>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 <script>
         $( "#id").select2({ placeholder: "Select Franchise" });
 </script>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please take some time to follow the [Stack Overflow tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [How do I write a good answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)